# Getting SyncTeX to work with Emacs, AucTeX and Skim (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac, forward-inverse-search

I'm attempting to set up LaTeX to work with Emacs on my Mac, running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5. I can compile everything all right, but I'm unable to use forward/inverse searches with Skim.

From reading other answers, I've attempted to adjust my `~/.emacs`, and create a `~/.latexmkrc` file. Here is what I'm currently using:

- **`~/.emacs`**:

```lisp
;; Tells emacs where to find LaTeX.
(let ((my-path (expand-file-name "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin")))
(setenv "PATH" (concat my-path ":" (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path my-path)) 

;; AucTeX settings
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
(lambda ()
  (push
   '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
     :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))

(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))

(custom-set-variables
     '(TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
     '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
     '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t))
```

- **`~/.latexmkrc`**:

  ```
  $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
  $pdf_previewer = 'open -a skim';
  $clean_ext = 'bbl rel %R-blx.bib %R.synctex.gz';
  ```

I've also set my Sync settings in Skim to use the Emacs preset. Does anyone have any ideas or resources I could look at to attempt to get forward and inverse searches working? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've managed to get inverse search running. I was saving my `~/.latexmkrc` file in Rich Text Format as opposed to plaintext. Converting to plaintext, going to `Skim -> Preferences -> Sync`, selecting Custom and entering `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient` appears to have corrected my inverse search issues.

Unfortunately, forward search is still not working. I can compile my TeX documents in Emacs just fine using `C-c C-c`, but `C-c C-v` does not go from the TeX file to the corresponding line in the PDF output in Skim. Once again, I would appreciate any advice on this!

**UPDATE 2:** Forward search appears to be working just fine now. The file I was originally experimenting on had spaces in the filename, which may have caused some hiccups with all this. Forward search works perfectly on one of my better named files.

Comment: Your description what happens is a bit short. How do you start inverse search in Skim and what happens? How did you customise Skim?

Comment: Hello @Keks, thank you for your response! I've added a small update, and I _think_ I've fixed the inverse search issues with Skim. Forward search is still proving troublesome.

Comment: @Jesse - I'm not on OS X, but you could try to guard the file names with ``""`` and see if that helps: `(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n \"%o\" \"%b\"")))`

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but in my case the file name guarding doesn't help. If I explicitly run, e.g., `/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g 6 "main.pdf" "introduction.tex"`, I get the output `571:633: execution error: Skim got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)` -- did you encounter any problems like this?

Comment: getting the same error here. help anyone?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall getting that particular error. Sorry!