# Emacs AUCTex pdf view show current page

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am new to Emacs AUCTex. I've been using Texstudio and Texshop before. I find two functions in Texstudio and Texshop very useful but I do not know how to do it in Emacs AUCTex.

1. In Texstudio and Texshop, if I want to compile and view the pdf file that results from the tex file I am editing, all I need is to click "build and view" (Texstudio) or "typesetting" (Texshop), and I will see the page which corresponds to where my cursor is in the tex file. But in Emacs+AUCTex, if I use `c-c c-v`, the pdf file compiled will always start from the first page. I wonder if there is a way to change this.
2. In Texstudio and Texshop, I do not need to close the pdf file, and every time I compile it, it will be automatically rebuilt. But in Emacs+AUCTex, if I did not close the pdf file, I cannot just make changes to the tex file and compile/view the new pdf file. I wonder if there is a way to change this.

I think there should be solutions online. But I am not sure how to formulate my questions accurately, so I cannot find solutions myself. I hope I make my questions clear enough.

Comment: What system are you using?  What viewer?

Comment: I am using Mac OS Sierra. And I use Adebe Acrobat or Skim.

Comment: I don't think anyone uses Adobe Reader when working with LaTeX, it doesn't even have SyncTeX support and, at least on Windows, it locks files preventing them from being compiled (I don't know what it does on other systems).  Regarding Skim, AUCTeX seems to not enable by default forward/inverse search with this viewer.  Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316787/getting-synctex-to-work-with-emacs-auctex-and-skim-os-x-el-capitan#comment773610_316787) help?